# How can I configure Windows Firewall without turning the service on?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2003, windows-firewall

I suddenly could not RDP into my server after rebooting it. Turned out the Firewall was blocking me, I remotely shut off the firewall service (parallels virtuozzo panel) and was able to RDP in. When I went to add my office IP to the firewall to allow me to connect, it won't launch the control panel unless I enable the Windows Firewall. If I do that, it kicks me off of RDP naturally. So how on earth can I configure this thing?

*(cross-posted from Serverfault)*

Comment: I found out that if I recycle firewall RDP will work for a short while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `netsh` – all settings are under the `firewall` context.

- To quickly open RDP, run `netsh fire add port TCP 3389 "Remote Desktop"`
- To manage other settings, run `netsh`, enter `firewall`, and use `?` to list commands.

You can also edit the settings on Registry directly (`regedit`), under `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy`. (This even works over the network, assuming Remote Registry is running.)

- For Remote Desktop, under the key `StandardProfile\GloballyOpenPorts\List` add a string value named `3389:TCP` with the data `3389:TCP:*:Enabled:Remote Desktop`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Local Security policy Admin tool.  There is a section for Windows firewall.

[image]

Comment: Is it that? (see edit to your answer) I don't see it..

Comment: Ok, the registry edit worked from chosen answer.

Comment: "IP Security Policies" refers to [IPsec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec), not the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make settings changes in the Group Policy Editor without the service running.

GPEdit.msc -> Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> IP Security Policies.

Comment: "IP Security Policies" refers to [IPsec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec), not the firewall.